# Pretty URL with $_GET method

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new to coding, so additional explanation would be greatly appreciated. So far I was able to remove the file extensions with my htaccess file.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# Does not apply to existing directories, if directory exist then don't run the rule

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

In the "dashboard" directory I have another index.php (displayed only to users logged in). In the index I have a $_GET method to retrieve the status of the user. So when I access localhost/project/dashboard/ I am able to view the index.php.

When I want to use the GET method my url would be something like localhost/project/dashboard/?status=active, which I am trying to change to localhost/project/dashboard/active or localhost/project/dashboard/status/active.

I am working in a localhost environment and my directories are broken down like this.

```
MAIN
- includes
- dashboard
|
-- subfolder
|-- somefile.php
|
-- index.php
- css
index.php
login.php
logout.php
.htaccess ** (this is the file im working with)
```

I am using the URL: http://localhost/project/dashboard/active

I have tried adding the following lines to my .htaccess

1.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /?status=$1 [NC,L,QSA] - doesn't work
```

Object not found! Error 404

2.

```
RewriteRule ^dashboard/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /?status=$1 [NC,L,QSA] - doesn't work
```

Redirects to localhost/dashboard

3.

IF I create ANOTHER .htaccess inside the "dashboard" directory and use write 1 line

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ index.php?status=$1 [NC,L,QSA] - WORKS
```

However, when using the 3rd method I CANNOT access the subfolder or its files in the dashboard.
So if I try to access localhost/project/dashboard/subfolder/somefile it returns
"Object not found!" Error 404

If I try to access localhost/project/dashboard/subfolder/somefile.php it redirects to localhost/project/dashboard/

There are going to be more folders and subfolders later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading Hanna's suggestion I tweaked the file path.

```
RewriteRule ^dashboard/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ dashboard/?status=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Try

`RewriteRule ^project/dashboard/(.*)$ project/dashboard/?status=$1 [L]`

Comment: Unfortunately, Internal Server Error - The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.